# Selection sort Max to end

Tags: selection-sort

This is my first question or time on this site so sorry if i do anything wrong. I have been trying to get this to work for my class. my eclipse has been broken for a little while so i have been coding blind as i cant find the end result or run and execute my programs. a classmate told me this question of mine was wrong but won't tell me what. it is supposed to be a selection sort that takes the greatest integers to the end then print after each pass. this looks right to me please help.

```
public class selectSort {
public static void Sort (){
int[] num= {5,20,8,6,7,1,3,11,15,9};
int i;
int n;
int temp; 
for (i=num.length-1; i>0; i--){
        int first=0;
        for(n= 1; n >= i; n++){
            if( num[n] > num[first])
                first=n;
            }
        temp = num[first];
        num[first] = num[i];
        num[i] = temp; 
        System.out.println(num);
    }}}
```

Comment: Your first goal should be to get your IDE working. Reinstall eclipse, or use some other editor, but it is seriously a dumb idea to work without being able to test anything. Your inner loop should go from 1 to i-1, not 1 to i.

Comment: tried that deleted it and cleaned all relevant data from the system and reinstalled it did nothing still cant run

Comment: Try an IDE like Dr. Java then, something just to test your code, and do the actual programming in eclipse. Also, make sure you have an up to date copy of the jdk and it is set up correctly.

Comment: ok thanks is that the only thing you could find wrong with it?

Comment: From what I can tell, I can't run it either, I'm on mobile.